# The total variation of a complex measure

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $\Omega$ be a locally compact and Hausdorff topological space.  The Riesz representation theorem says that $C_0(\Omega)^*$ , dual of the commutative C*-algebra $C_0(\Omega)$, is just the space of complex Radon measures $M(\Omega)$.

$$\gamma: M(\Omega)\simeq C_0(\Omega)^* : \gamma(\mu)(f)=\int f d\mu$$

Let $\mu$ be a complex Radon measure and denote $[\mu]$, by the total variation of $\mu$.

Question:  It seems that $\gamma([\mu])=|\gamma(\mu)|$, where $|\gamma(\mu|)$ is the absolute value of the bounded linear functional $\gamma(\mu)$ on $C_0(\Omega)$ ?

Comment: Maybe there is some misunderstanding, but $\gamma([\mu])$ is linear, while $|\mu|$ is not.

Comment: @FanZheng From the surrounding context I think $|\mu|$ should be $|\gamma(\mu)|$ where the latter is understood as the absolute value of a functional on a $*$-algebra, hence is itself a linear functional

Comment: @YemonChoi How is the absolute value of a functional on a *-algebra defined?

Comment: @FanZheng Well, perhaps this only works for normal functionals on a von Neumann algebra, I admit I'm a bit sketchy on the details. But for such a functional $f$ it can be factorized as $f=u\cdot g$ where $h$ is a positive normal functional and $u$ is a partial isometry in the (von Neumann) algebra

Comment: @FanZheng, thanks. I did your comment. As you said I just focus on von Neumann algebras.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could define more explicitly the objects you are talking about, so that people don't have to guess about the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is directly obtained by  the following interesting fact:

Theorem. Let $M$ be a von neumann algebra and $f$ be a normal functional on $M$. 
Assume $a$ is in the unit  ball of $M$ with $||af||=|f||$ and $af$ is positive. Then $af$ is just the absolute value of $|f|$. (see  theorem 3.2 in Order ideals in a C*-algebra and its dual by E. Effros 1962)

Comment: If you are going to answer your own question, please provide details of how this theorem answers your question